# Let W and Z be two random variables such that W ≤ Z. Show that for any ε > 0, P(W > ε) ≤ P(Z > ε).

Tags: probability-theory

I feel like I should be able to use Markov's Inequality, but have not found an effective way to use it for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $W\leq Z$, if $W>\varepsilon$ then $Z>\varepsilon$. In other words
$$ \{W>\varepsilon\}\subset \{Z>\varepsilon\}$$
hence $\mathbb{P}(W>\varepsilon)\leq \mathbb{P}(Z>\varepsilon)$.